# If each $X_i$ is distributed $N(0, \sigma^2)$, what is the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^k X_i^2$?

Tags: normal-distribution

I tried it for $k=1$  with an integral, so:
$P(X^2 <x) = \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} e^{\frac{t^2}{\sigma^2}} dt$, but this didn't work out.
I suspect there is faster method to solve this, especially because I need the sum.

Comment: "In probability theory and statistics, the chi-squared distribution (also chi-square or χ²-distribution) with k degrees of freedom is the distribution of a sum of the squares of k independent standard normal random variables."
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution

You can have a look at the proofs:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_related_to_chi-squared_distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you standardize by dividing $X$ by $\sigma$ so $Y=X/\sigma$ is $N(0,1)$, then the sum of $Y_i^2$ is $\chi^2_k$.